# Как получить свойство вложенного объекта в переборе циклом файла json?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть json объект:

```
{
    "Theme" : {
        "White": {
            "color" : "#FFFFFF",
            "label" : "#000000"
        },
        "Black": {
            "color" : "#000000",
            "label" : "#FFFFFF"
        }
    }
}
```

Мне нужно в цикле получить свойство вложенного объекта (использую ejs для шаблонизации).

```
     <% for (var theme in colors["Theme"]) { %>
        <div class="blocks-container__item">
          <div class="color-block">
            <div class="color-block__inner" style="background-color: <%= theme["color"] %>; color: <%= theme["label"] %>;">
              <span class="color-block__name"><%= theme %></span>
              <span class="color-block__hex"><%= theme["color"] %></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% } %>
```

Такой код у меня не работает. Как добраться до вложенных свойств?

Comment: Что то мне кажется `"Theme"` должен быть массивом а не объектом? `"Theme" : [...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то вот так можно сделать:

```js
let colors = {
    "Theme" : {
      "White": {
          "color" : "#FFFFFF",
          "label" : "#000000"

      },
        "Black": {
          "color" : "#000000",
          "label" : "#FFFFFF"

      }
    }
}


for(let a in colors.Theme){
    console.log(colors.Theme[a].color)
}
```

Т.е. код должен быть что то на подобии

```
<% for (var theme in colors.Theme) { %>
        <div class="blocks-container__item">
          <div class="color-block">
            <div class="color-block__inner" style="background-color: <%= theme["color"] %>; color: <%= theme["label"] %>;">
              <span class="color-block__name"><%= theme %></span>
              <span class="color-block__hex"><%= colors.Theme[theme].color %></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% } %>
```

Но есть такое чувство что `"Theme"` должен быть массивом а не объектом:

```js
let colors = {
    "Theme" : [
        {"White": {
            "color" : "#FFFFFF",
            "label" : "#000000"
        }
        },
        {"Black": {
            "color" : "#000000",
            "label" : "#FFFFFF"
        }
        }
    ]
}

colors.Theme.forEach((e,i)=>{
    for(let c in e){
        console.log(e[c].color)
    }
})
```